# Collatz Conjecture Script - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on the Longest Collatz problem in the Project Euler archives, and can't figure out why mine is taking such a long time. I've compared it to other successful scripts, which often take just seconds.

The code follows below, but the idea is that for every number in the given range, the program begins brute forcing the descent. If, at any point in the descent it finds a number it's already seen and worked out a descent for, it simply adds the length of the current descent to the previously determined one.

The other code I've seen does this too, I can't figure out why mine doesn't give it the extra speed. I've run it with ranges up to 1,000 and it works fine and spits out all right answers, but around 10,000 it slows way down, and my target is 1,000,000

For the record, I am *extremely* new to programming (been working on Python for maybe a week), but very familiar with number theory.

EDIT: Slightly tweaked code, thanks to Glibdud!

```
collatz_dic = {1:3}
d=1

for x in range(1,10001):
    collatz_list = [x]
    while x != 1:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            x = x/2
            collatz_list.append(x)
            if x in collatz_dic.keys() == True:
                collatz_dic[d] = ((len(collatz_list)-1) + collatz_dic.get(x))
            else:
                collatz_dic[d] = (len(collatz_list)-1)
        else:
            x = (3*x)+1
            collatz_list.append(x)
            if x in collatz_dic.keys() == True:
                collatz_dic[d] = ((len(collatz_list)-1) + collatz_dic.get(x))
            else:
                collatz_dic[d] = (len(collatz_list)-1)
    d = d+1

print(max(collatz_dic, key=collatz_dic.get))
```

Comment: Python dicts are optimized for finding keys, not values, so the `if x in collatz_dic.values() == True:` lines are probably contributing.

Comment: But it should be looking for a key. I tried it with a much smaller range (1:10) and it produced a dictionary that looked like this:
{1:3, 2:1, 3:7, 4:2, 5:5, 6:8, 7:16, 8:3, 9:19}. The key is the starting num, the value is the length of the descent. My script should recognize numbers that are keys, and add the value of that key to the length of it's current descent.

Comment: Oops, it wasn't. I replaced `if x in collatz_dic.values() == True:` with `if x in collatz_dic.keys() == True:` which still runs although that doesn't seem to have sped it up at all.

Comment: Are you sure this is generating the correct answers? If I change 10001 to 1001, I get 871, but I think the correct answer should be 178?

Comment: Also, when I change both occurences of `if x in collatz_dic.values()` to `if x in collatz_dic.keys()`, it speeds the runtime up significantly. It can still be a lot more efficient, but that appears to be the biggest issue.

Comment: Wiki says 871 is it. Do you have any hits as to how I might improve the efficiency. I did what you just said and it did work, although I'm still nowhere close to the 1-min time limit stipulated Project Euler and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

The more significant logic flaw in this code is this statement:

```
if x in collatz_dic.keys() == True:
    collatz_dic[d] = ((len(collatz_list)-1) + collatz_dic.get(x))
else:
    collatz_dic[d] = (len(collatz_list)-1)
```

(Both occurances which can collapse into one.)  There should be a `break` after the first `collatz_dic[d]` assignment as you now know the answer, so stop your loop!  The `else` clause doesn't belong here, but rather should be an `else` clause of the `while` loop as we don't know the answer at this point, so why keep saving the current value into the dictionary.

Minor coding issues inlclude: the bulk of the two halves of the `if` can be collapsed into common code; the `collatz_list` doesn't need to be a list, simply a counter; you don't want to do:

```
if x in collatz_dic.keys() == True:
```

but rather:

```
if x in collatz_dic:
```

as you don't need to build a new data structure to search when you have a particularly fast one in hand.  Putting all these fixes together with some style changes, we get:

```
collatz_dic = {1: 3}

for d in range(2, 1_000_001):
    x = d

    collatz_count = 0

    while x != 1:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            x = x / 2
        else:
            x = 3 * x + 1

        collatz_count += 1

        if x in collatz_dic:
            collatz_count += collatz_dic[x]
            break

    collatz_dic[d] = collatz_count

print(max(collatz_dic, key=collatz_dic.get))
```

Which solves for 1,000,000 (837,799) in under five seconds, well within the 1 minute time limit.